# Object or Complement

Tags: sentence-patterns

The professor wants to retire.
Here 'to retire' is used as object or complement?
Also, in "The man gave Amy some good advice"
Is 'some good advice' an object or complement?

Comment: *This is off the top of my head, so take it with a grain of salt.* In the first one, *to retire* is a *subject complement*, because it modifies the subject, which is *the professor*. In the second one, *Amy* is the *object* and *some good advice* is the *object complement*, because it modifies *Amy* not *the man*.

Comment: I felt, Amy is Indirect object and Some good advice is direct object. Similarly, 'to retire' seems to be an object too!!

Comment: @miracles You are definitely right, but here's a slight correction. *Some good* isn't part of the DO; only *advice* is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *The professor wants to retire*, **to retire** is the verb in an ***Infinitive [Object Complement Clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf)***. That means that it is a clause, with an infinitive verb, that functions as the Direct Object of the verb *wants*.

**Complement clauses** are noun clauses that can be either subjects or objects; there are four kinds in English: infinitives, gerunds, embedded questions, or tensed *That*-clauses. This is the only way I ever use the term.

Other than this use, *complement* is a term that is used with a wide variety of meanings. Since most of these meanings add no more information than "something that completes a phrase or clause", they're mostly unhelpful and are best avoided.

The subject of the complement clause is deleted because it's identical with the subject of *want* (*The professor*), and [*want* is a verb that governs A-Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Comment: +1 or more. Who are "The Cliffs"?

Comment: There is a series of study guides for college students in the United States called _Cliff's Review of ..._, which students just call _the Cliff's on ..._, and the phrase has come to represent any short, dense review of a topic.

Comment: I forgot to add, in _The man gave Amy some good advice_, _Amy_ is the indirect object, and _some good advice_ is direct object. This is also true for _The man gave some good advice to Amy_, which is related through the Dative alternation.

Answer (score 8):

*Complement* is used to describe ‘a phrase or clause that completes the meaning required by some other form’ (Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English), bearing in mind that a phrase can consist of one word. To that extent, *to retire* and *some good advice* in your examples are complements. However, it would be usual to describe them more precisely as *direct objects*. They can be both a noun phrase, as in *some good advice*, and a clause, as in *to retire*.